# How and where to update RolePrincipal?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, global-asax, roleprovider, principal

I'm using asp.net FormAuthentication and a custom role manager. I would like to add a custom Identity to the User object so I can store some custom user data in the User object and still have all the roles functionality.

I'm kind of confused as to where I should be doing this (which global.asax method) how should I update the RolePrincipal object? I can't seem to find any information of this.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down, but I figured it out

Comment: Your question is vague which is why people down voted. What kind of problems are you encountering? You want to restrict file/folder access based on the logged-in user's authrorized roles? Btw, I did not down voted ;)

Comment: I am looking for a good solution to this exact same problem. Did you find anything?